# Extra cables for the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I just got this new Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 from USA and I love it. However, I'm not the most organized person, and sometime I lose my cables. The GT has a special cable, which is not using the common connector. Is there a model-specific cable I have to order, or does any cable for similar Samsung Tab device will just work ? I saw third-party companies selling such cables. I don't mind paying some money for this, but this is basically essential for my tablet to recharge and exchange any large quantity of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung sells [replacement data cable](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab-accessories/ECC1DP0UBEGSTA).

Comment: Yeah. That's an easy reply. But Samsung doe snot sell directly to consumers. At lest not in Canada. I got cables from some other resellers. I found that Belkin has some cable too, coupled with a car power supply that provides power for recharge.